# inserting rows in the database and updating the rows below it

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

hi there im currently working a system that compares 2 pages typed by 2 person and edit but first i insert the data's into the database per line so output looks like this

one

two

three

four

five

six

and this is the database

```
id   pagenum  linenum   data   bookname
1       1        1      one    twilight
2       1        2      two    twilight
3       1        3      three  twilight
4       1        4      four   twilight
5       1        5      five   twilight
6       1        6      six    twilight
```

but i want to insert 2 lines in between id number 2 and 3 and update the linenumber on it and below it
so im gonna query the line number above where i will put it so query linenumb where id= 2+1 so 3 will be the starting line number of the 2 rows i will add so it will be line 3 and 4 but the dilema is there will be 2 pagenum=1 linenum=3 and pagenum=1 and linenum=4 can someone help me with the structure how to fix it

so after all of it the database should look like this

```
id   pagenum  linenum   data   bookname
1       1        1      one    twilight
2       1        2      two    twilight
7       1        3    newline  twilight //this is the 1st line i added
8       1        4    newline  twilight //this is the 2nd line i added
3       1        5      three  twilight
4       1        6      four   twilight
5       1        7      five   twilight
6       1        8      six    twilight
```

im having a dilema what to put in line number of the added lines should i queue them like that

like insert into... 2 and 3
count where the starting value should be 3+1 the count for will be how many times it will update and increment and then update the bottom page
or leave the line number blank and
count the whole page and update them

or should i move all the datas 2 rows down? like this

```
id   pagenum  linenum   data   bookname
1       1        1      one    twilight
2       1        2      two    twilight
3       1        3    newline  twilight 
4       1        4    newline  twilight 
5       1        5      three  twilight
6       1        6      four   twilight
7       1        7      five   twilight//i moved this 2 rows down and so this is the inserted value
6       1        8      six    twilight//i moved this 2 rows down and so this is the inserted value
```

which is the easiest and best effective way

Comment: And your question is ? What have you tried and what was the problem ?

Comment: i dont know what to put in line number in the newlines i will add
will i put 3 and 4 or leave it blank and query the whole page and update the whole page

Comment: suggestion: first step: Where-ever you are inserting, update the subsequent records first (in the above example, before the insert, run UPDATE foo SET linenum = linenum+2 WHERE linenum >=3)  Then 2nd step, insert

Comment: @AgRizzo i dont think i need to do something about the top rows the only issue is the new row and the bottom rows pls correct me if im wrong im still new at php and MySql

Comment: @JoseSamaniego - You don't understand my suggestion.  Run the UPDATE then the INSERT. "Top rows" is not a great term, but I assume you are referring to rows with a linenum that will not be changed. If so, look at the WHERE clause of the UPDATE.  No records are updated that are "above" the rows that will be INSERTED

Comment: oh sorry for the misunderstanding now i get you and will try your suggestion thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identify the line number that you will start to insert from (3).

Then get the number of rows you're inserting (2).

```
<?php
    $start = 3;
    $rows = 2;
?>
```

Then you run this query:

```
UPDATE table SET linenum = linenum + $rows WHERE linenum >= $start
```

This will make your table look like:

```
id   pagenum  linenum   data   bookname
1       1        1      one    twilight
2       1        2      two    twilight
3       1        5      three  twilight
4       1        6      four   twilight
5       1        7      five   twilight
6       1        8      six    twilight
```

Now you have a gap for your new rows, so insert them.

Comment: ok thats great so let me clarify so 1st i will make a gap then update the linenumbers below it before i insert the new rows?

Comment: Yes. You are updating all the line number underneath where you will insert so that they are ready for your insert.